# React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Just updated my application from ES5 to ES6. After doing so, I'm running into this warning from react:

```
React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number
```

I believe this has to do with my load order, but I can't seem to find where exactly. The error occurred after converting the `HeaderContainer` to es6 syntax

**entry.js**

```
require('babel-polyfill');
require('expose?React!react');
require('expose?ReactDOM!react-dom');
require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery');

require('expose?HeaderContainer!./header/HeaderContainer.jsx');
```

**HeaderContainer.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <nav id="header" className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          This should work
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>App Name here</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'bundle' %>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-header-container"></div>

    <script>
      var headerContainer = React.createElement(HeaderContainer);

      ReactDOM.render(headerContainer, document.getElementById('react-header-container'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './app/frontend/javascripts/entry.js',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/assets',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules'],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  React: 'react',
  ReactDOM: 'react-dom',
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app-name-here",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --progress --colors --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.11"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery-mask-plugin": "^1.13.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.14.4",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting the component incorrectly. There's currently no default export, so when you're requiring the file you're not actually importing the component itself.

```
export default class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {

    return (
      <nav id="header" className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          This should work
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i've tried this already, and just retried it. unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: if you add a debugger statement to the script tag prior to the creation of the HeaderContainer element and log the value of HeaderContainer to the console, what do you see?

Comment: prior to var headerContainer = React... there no errors. After running that line, i'm getting the error. Calling HeaderContainer in the console returns back:  HeaderContainer: Object {__esModule: true}

Comment: ya there shouldnt be an error because you havent attempted to use the HeaderContainer at that point. im pretty sure that the import is missing the component, if you make the component the default export the object will contain a default property pointing to the component. that default property should then be the value passed to React.createElement.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your .babelrc file? Here is an example .babelrc. This file is used to configure babel, you have to create it yourself:

```
{
  "presets":["react", "es2015"]
}
```

It should be placed in your apps root directory.

EDIT

Try this, replace `babel-loader` with `babel`

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: why would you need a .babelrc when the presets are specified in webpack.config.js

Comment: You shouldn't need it(.babelrc that is)...but you are experiencing unexpected behaviour with the new ES6 syntax. So, It seemed like a logical  troubleshooting step to try adding the default config file for babel(webpack will just ignore it if it isn't needed). If it works with the .babelrc file, and it doesn't work without it - you know there is a problem with your webpack.config.